# HTML in GET request is a "Bad Request" only on one server

Tags: php, html, get, request

I'm developing a content uploading tool that is currently GETing the html data in the URL

(For example: "`this is my <strong>content<strong>` --submit--> `http://site.com/?content=this+is+my+<strong>+content+<strong>`)

I realize this is a bad way to do it and I'm working on a replacement but I'll need this to work for my users for the time being.

When I tested this on my machine (virtual host) it worked fine, but now that I have it up on my Nexcess server it returns "bad request." I assume this has something to do with a Nexcess setting?

[Here is an example](http://veganfm.nextmp.net/wp-content/themes/veganfm/classes/additem.php?food-name=&food-source=&testingName=&testing-source=&theName=Alive!&theCity=San%20Francisco&theState=California&theCountry=United%20States&theAddress=1972%20Lombard%20Street%20San%20Francisco%20CA&theLat=37.800409&theLng=-122.43401900000003&location=Alive%20Restaurant,%20Lombard%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA&status%5B%5D=Vegan&place-source=alive&content=%3Cp%20align=%22left%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size%3a%20large;%22%3EA%20soothing%20urban%20oasis%20in%20the%20midst%20of%20bustling%20Lombard%20Street,%20Alive!%20takes%20healthful%20dining%20to%20a%20sophisticated%20new%20level.%20Specializing%20in%20raw,%20vegetarian,%20animal-free%20cuisine%20using%20the%20freshest,%20highest-quality%20local%20and%20seasonal%20produce,%20the%20restaurant%20was%20awarded%20Best%20Raw%20Food%20in%20San%20Francisco%20by%20SF%20Weekly.%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%20align=%22left%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size%3a%20large;%22%3EClean,%20lively%20flavors%20are%20the%20hallmark%20of%20this%20distinctive%20cuisine.%20%E2%80%9CIt%E2%80%99s%20food%20that%E2%80%99s%20healthy,%20well-balanced%20and%20delicious,%20prepared%20as%20fresh%20as%20possible,%E2%80%9D%20says%20owner%20and%20executive%20chef%20Leland%20Jung.%20In%20keeping%20with%20raw%20food%E2%80%99s%20core%20philosophies,%20most%20of%20the%20dishes%20on%20the%20menu%20are%20prepared%20without%20being%20heated%20above%20118%20degrees,%20to%20preserve%20optimal%20nutritional%20value%20and%20promote%20healthful%20digestion.%20The%20restaurant%20does%20not%20serve%20meat%20or%20any%20animal%20products%20%28including%20dairy%20and%20honey%29,%20as%20well%20as%20wheat%20or%20grains.%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%20align=%22left%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size%3a%20large;%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ERestaurant%20Design%3C/strong%3E%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Ctable%20width=%22296%22%20border=%220%22%20align=%22right%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%20width=%22290%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20align=%22right%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22http://www.aliveveggie.com/graphics/AliveDinner.jpg%22%20alt=%22%22%20width=%22250%22%20height=%22207%22%20border=%221%22%20/%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/td%3E%0D%0A%3C/tr%3E%0D%0A%3C/tbody%3E%0D%0A%3C/table%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%20align=%22left%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size%3a%20large;%22%3EThe%20interior%20design%20of%20the%20restaurant%20was%20conceived%20after%20a%20consultation%20with%20a%20feng%20shui%20expert.%20Muted%20olive%20and%20sage%20tones%20on%20the%20wall%20form%20a%20tranquil%20backdrop%20for%20the%20simple,%20minimal%20Asian-inspired%20table%20accessories%3a%20celadon%20vases,%20flickering%20red%20votives,%20and%20bamboo%20mats.%20Padded%20bench%20seating%20creates%20intimacy,%20while%20abstract%20light%20fixtures%20with%20plant-like%20forms%20echo%20the%20organic%20theme.%20The%20focus%20of%20the%20space%20lies%20on%20two%20oversized%20pieces%20of%20wall%20art%3a%20a%20backlit%20abstract%20textile%20panel%20created%20by%20Jung%20himself,%20and%20a%20nine-panel%20canvas%20by%20a%20local%20graphic%20artist%20consisting%20of%20hand-painted%20Japanese%20papers%20applied%20in%20layers%20to%20form%20organic%20shapes.%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%20align=%22left%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size%3a%20large;%22%3EThe%20garden%20is%20a%20true%20retreat%20from%20urban%20life.%20Decking%20of%20sustainable%20ip%C3%A9%20wood,%20redwood%20fencing,%20and%20an%20arching%20canopy%20of%20plum%20trees%20create%20shelter%20for%20a%20small%20grouping%20of%20teak%20tables%20and%20chairs.%20Japanese%20maple,%20bamboos,%20camellias,%20ferns,%20and%20vines%20form%20an%20eclectic%20yet%20soothing%20planting%20scheme.%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%20align=%22left%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size%3a%20large;%22%3EThe%20restaurant%20received%20perfect%20scores%20of%20100%20for%20cleanliness%20from%20the%20Department%20of%20Public%20Health%20for%20the%20last%20two%20years.%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E&type=place) of one such request.

Is there some sort of setting I could turn off for the time being?

Comment: BTW: Your example is a get request, not a post request.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I'll edit.

Comment: Not that it matters, I still got a bad-request back from the get request.

Comment: No it might matter. It was always a get request. I just wrote it wrong here. I'll give the post request a shot.

Comment: Normally, this would be explained in the servers error log....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are, it is because the URL is to long (specifically the query string).

By the looks of it, you are *not* POSTing the data, but are GETing the data. Simply switching the form from GET to POST will likely fix the problem, since POST data is not nearly as restricted in length as GET data tends to be.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in the URL string it is a GET not a POST.  This could be your issue, depending on how you're interpreting it on the page.

It may also not like that you have `?food-name=&food-source=`.  You may not be defining a required value for one of these keys.

### EDIT

I would check that all of the character encoding is done properly.  But really, this is the sort of thing that you're going to want to do through post, not with a get request...

## 2nd EDIT

When I tested this string on my own server and printed out the resulting `$_GET` array this is what I got:

```
Array
(
    [food-name] => 
    [food-source] => 
    [testingName] => 
    [testing-source] => 
    [theName] => Alive!
    [theCity] => San%20Francisco
    [theState] => California
    [theCountry] => United%20States
    [theAddress] => 1972%20Lombard%20Street%20San%20Francisco%20CA
    [theLat] => 37.800409
    [theLng] => -122.43401900000003
    [location] => Alive%20Restaurant,%20Lombard%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA
    [status%5B%5D] => Vegan
    [place-source] => alive
    [type] => place
)
```

You probably recognize from that array, that a lot of the query string is missing in the array.  Somewhere in there the query string has an error.  My server doesn't throw an error though, it just stops reading the string.

Comment: (to your second point) True, but that would probably return a php error on the next page than a bad request error.

Comment: agreed, but I'm guessing that there is an error in the query string that it isn't liking.  This really should be done through POST.

Comment: Mos def. I'm trying that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server software.

Extremely long URLs are usually a mistake. URLs over 2,000 characters will not work in the most popular web browser. Don't use them if you intend your site to work for the majority of Internet users.

So I would say in your case, absolutely there is no way you can guarantee that it will work. it really depend on the length of the URL, Server type and the browser your clients are using.

Maybe [gzcompress()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) can help you. But this will result in not allowed characters, so you will have to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) too. but again, you really need to consider not to use GET in here :)